# Initial project set up for SVN

Tags: svn, netbeans, tortoisesvn

I am new to the concept of respositories and have read up some on SVN, but the workflow confuses me, perhaps it is the terminology/jargon but I was hoping if someone could clarify my confusion.

Basically if I have code on a server in a path say home/public_html/site and with to use version control with svn I would install svn server in say home/svn and then create a directory for the site called home/svn/site.

I understand that if I wish to use that code on a local pc (say Netbeans/XAMPP and TortoiseSVN) I'd first check-out the project, make changes, add the files I want to update, and when ready  update so that the svn repo is up to date with my changes.

My confusion lies here:

1) How do I get the initial repo code in home/svn/site? Do I copy it there from public_html/site?

2) A related question of course is where do I do my initial check-out from? public_html/site or /svn/site?

3) Finally, if I want to see the changes in my live code (/public_html/site) how does the svb/site repo sync with it?

Any clarifications would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The typical workflow for creating a new repository on a (centralized) version control system is:

- Create a new empty repository on a server
- Checkout (clone) the (empty) repository into a *working copy* on a development workstation
- Put all source- and project-files in the *working copy* on your development station
- *commit* the new files to put them on the repository. Only commit source- and project-files (not the built files) (For `Git` there is https://www.gitignore.io/ where you can search for different project-types like *NetBeans*-projects. It tells you which files/directories should not be under version control.)
- When someone else makes changes to your project, you *update* to get those changes into your working copy by pulling them down from the repository

Theoretically you could *checkout* the repository on your live webserver (assuming it's a web-application you're building) but probably **you don't want stuff like the *NetBeans*-project-files on your live server**.

Therefore consider a **build/publish-script**. (I'm not sure how *NetBeans* handles this.) Typically this script would generate an `out`-directory which you can publish on the live server. (Of course you don't put the `out`-directory under version control, just the build-script.)

You might want to create *branches* or *tags* for every version you deploy on your live server so you can keep track of them.

Comment: Hmm ok thank you. I already have working copy on the dev server. We installed SVN on the Server. We installed Netbeans on the desktop along with Tortoise which can  now check out from that SVN. The idea is that the coder  will work on the desktop make changes and update/commit  back to the server repo. I was told that the simplest way to then have the repo updated code become the working code on the server is just to do an  rsycn either on timed intervals or triggered on any commit to the repo from the desktop, does that sound right and/or in keeping with the above?

Comment: `rsync` could indeed be a part of the solution for the **build/publish-script**.